# convert with -resample changes background to black

Tags: command-line, convert, jpeg

When I create a pdf and use convert to increase the image resolution, for some reason the background is changed to black.    Here's an example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\Huge \bf
Please leave deliveries\\
for the White House \\
in the carport \\
$\Longleftarrow$
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you create a pdf of this file--call it foo.pdf--and then type

```
convert -background white -resample 200 foo.pdf foo.jpg
```

You get an all black jpg file.''

I'm running 16.04 and the version of convert is

Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-06-11

Could somebody please advise?    Tahnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when converting a transparent image to jpg, a format that does not know an alpha channel. You can avoid the problem by adding the `-flatten` option to your command:

```
convert -resample 200 foo.pdf -flatten foo.jpg
```

It will compose the final image from the input taking transparency into account and defaulting to white background.